# How to "inherit" a class variable from ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm a little new to rails.

Say I want to do something like:

```
def is_admin?
 @admin = User.grab(session[:username]).admin
end
```

I can define this in the ApplicationController but then I have to call `is_admin?()` in every method in every subsequent controller. Is there a way around this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `:before_filter` at the start of each controller:

```
before_filter :is_admin
```

At least then you don't have to do it for every method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem with calling `is_admin?` is. Calling methods in Ruby is pretty cheap. You may want to "memoize" the return value to avoid calling to the database every time the method is called:

```
def is_admin?
  unless defined?(@is_admin)
    @is_admin = User.grab(session[:username]).admin
  end

  @is_admin
end
```

Since `is_admin?` can return a falsey value, `||=` won't work.